# How to translate string with link?

Tags: magento2, translate

Magento 2.3

How would I translate this in a CSV file:

```
$message = __('You added <a href="'. $product->getProductUrl() .'">%1</a> to your shopping cart.',
                    $product->getName()
                );
```

Tried several ways, but all failed. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the playground - [https://onlinegdb.com/rJQNGjQIU](https://onlinegdb.com/rJQNGjQIU)

This is the raw PHP implementation. Use the translate wherever necessary and write the appropriate translation in the CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

Example:

```
<?= __('Customer address <a href="%s">link</a>!', $this->getBaseUrl().'customer/address/') ?>
```

and then the string in the CSV file should have double quotes:

```
"Customer address <a href=""%s"">link</a>!"
```